Showing Updated row count as 0 after successfull execution of script
After executing my update script successfully I could see that Dbeaver statistics tab showing updated row count as 0. But the changes are updated and script is executed without any error. Does anyone know the reason ?.

script:

do $$
-- start a transaction
declare

success integer := -1;

err_context text := 'Error during script execution';

begin

UPDATE table1 p SET name= pt.name
FROM table2  pt WHERE p.id  = pt.tableid;


raise notice ' script executed Successfully';

exception

when others then

RAISE INFO 'Error Name:%',SQLERRM;
RAISE INFO 'Error State:%', SQLSTATE;
RAISE INFO 'Error Context:%', err_context;

end $$;


An update that changes nothing is technically still a successful operation if it went through at all - zero updated rows means it suceeded and it's you who requested that this update should only apply to rows matching criteria so strict no rows in the table matched them. Inspect table1 and table2 and see if they have any matching rows at all: select count(*) from table1 join table2 on table1.id=table2.tableid; - my guess that's zero.

GET DIAGNOSTICS integer_var = ROW_COUNT; and/or check the FOUND variable to keep track of longer operations. Check assertions.

Expanding on @Zegarek's comment is not much useful or informative that raise notice ' script executed Successfully'; instead of that declare a variable rows_affected int; and after your update instruction get diagnostics rows_affected = row_count;  raise notice 'Rows updated: %', rows_affected;

The DO command doesn't update any rows, even if commands within the code block do. DBeaver is correctly reporting the number of rows updated by the last command, which was DO.
